# When I run curl I get status 0

Tags: php, curl

I am using this code to get page from internet, but I get result status 0:

```
$url='http://www.jiwlp.com';

$this->url = $url;

if (isset($this->url)) {

    // start cURL instance 
    $this->ch = curl_init ();

    // this tells cUrl to return the data
    curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // set the url to download 
    curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url); 

    // follow redirects if any 
    curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 

    // tell cURL if the data is binary data or not 
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, $this->binary); 

    $useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);  
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

    // grabs the webpage from the internet 
    $this->html = curl_exec($this->ch);
    $this->status = curl_getinfo($this->ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    print_r(curl_getinfo($this->ch)); // closes the connection
    curl_close ($this->ch);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you format your code so we can distinguish the code from the comments?

Comment: Are you pasting the code because this line `curl_setopt ($this -> ch , CURLOPT_VERBOSE , 1 );` and the next have parse errors?

Comment: @ Martin Dimitrov  no when i run code this is the result i get: Array ( [url] => http://www.jiwlp.com [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this version works for me, removed the oo

```
$url = 'http://www.jiwlp.com';

if(isset($url)){
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,$binary);

    $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;
 rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: this is the result i am getting :Array ( [url] => http://www.jiwlp.com [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 )

Comment: Works for me. I am on 5.3.0. What version are you using? Try removing `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` since it is not used any more.

Answer (score 0):

The response status is already stored in `$this->status`, I'm assuming you are referring to HTTP response status codes, so instead of

```
// grabs the webpage from the internet 
$this->html = curl_exec($this->ch);  
$this->status = curl_getinfo($this->ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

print_r(curl_getinfo($this->ch));
```

Try printing out `$this->status` instead.

```
// grabs the webpage from the internet 
$this->html = curl_exec($this->ch);  
$this->status = curl_getinfo($this->ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

print_r($this->status);
```

Comment: `$this->status` is not an array. It holds the HTTP status code of the server response: 200, 404 etc

Comment: Ah yes, I edited my answer, I put 'I'm assuming you are referring to HTTP status codes'

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to get http site/link status:

```
<?php
function get_link_status($url, $timeout = 10) 
{
$ch = curl_init();
// set cURL options
$opts = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // do not output to browser
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,            // set URL
            CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,         // do a HEAD request only
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $timeout);   // set timeout
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
curl_exec($ch); // do it!
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // find HTTP status
curl_close($ch); // close handle
echo $status; //or return $status;
    //example of check
    if ($status == '301') { echo 'This is redirected';}
}

get_link_status('http://example.com');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

check CURL in php disabled function.

if CURL_EXEC is disabled in the webserver, php wont give error instead will [http_code] => 0 header_size] => 0 .......

run phpinfo() from a php page is one of a way to get the list of disabled php functions.